# ReactJS change array item in state error: Cannot assign to read only property of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'have a ReactJS event handler that need to change an array item, where the array is stored in component state. My code:

```
handleColumnResize = (index, width) => {
    let formData = Object.assign({}, this.state.formData);
    let columns = Object.assign({}, this.state.formData.columns);

    columns[index].width = width;

    formData.columns = columns;

    this.setState({
        formData: formData
    });

    if (this.props.onDataChange) this.props.onDataChange(formData);
};
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'width' of object '#<Object>'
```

At the line: `columns[index].width = width;`

What is the correct way to change the content of the state array item?

OBS: My question is different of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs) because if envolves changing an specific array item, no adding itens to a new array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Comment: What does your state look like originally? Is it a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object instead of a regular object?

Comment: It is a regular object. formData is my variable name...

Comment: Can you show up your state, the error means you're missing the coloumns in your formData. Then you cant set them coloumn width right. Or make a console.log(columns) bevore your error with line "columns[index].width = width;"

Answer (score 0):

Check this.state.formData.columns.You have point columns to this.state.formData.columns.The reason that you have this problem is that you want to change some properties in this.state.formData.columns.And you should debugger like this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(columns[index],width)
```

And check the  writable property.